# Change a sparse plot into a different

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sparse plot due to data input

Data input

```
dframe <- structure(list(value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
10L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 22L, 24L), level= c(1009L, 103L, 43L, 
7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

And the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=dframe, mapping = aes(x=value, y=level)) +
  geom_col(color = '#032838', fill = 'steelblue', size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = level), vjust = -0.4, size = 4, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Is there any alternative plot which will not be so sparse after frequency of 30 in x axis?

Comment: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Users' not found`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hypothesis: you could zoom in on the part of the plot where the data are more sparse. An example with `ggforce`

```
library(ggforce)
#transform your data to be plotted by geom_histogram (or geom_density)
df <- data.frame(value=rep(dframe$value,dframe$level))

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=value),dplyr::mutate(df, z = F),bins = 25,color = '#032838', fill = 'steelblue') +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=value),dplyr::mutate(df, z = T),bins =50,color = '#032838', fill = 'steelblue') + 
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(5, 25),ylim=c(0,10), horizontal = F,zoom.data = z,zoom.size=0.5)+
  theme(zoom.y = element_blank(), validate = FALSE)
```

which give you:
[image]

you can play with the `bins` argument to find the perfect solution for you.

N.B. I remove the `geom_text` part since you did not provide the `Users` variable

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take the logarithm of your `level` data?  That would be the standard thing to do in such a situation.  Consider:

```
p <- ggplot(data=dframe, mapping = aes(x=value, y=log(level))) +
     geom_col(color = '#032838', fill = 'steelblue', size = 1)
```

[image]